# synchronization other than current object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

i have a class called counter, in that stringbuffer instance and a integer variable is shared across two threads.

my question here is in the counter class i have used synchronized (buffer) ,buffer is nothing but a stringbuffer instance.

i haven't used synchronized (this).According to the concept of synchronization when we use synchronized block ,it will have a lock on the particular instance. if we used synchronized (this) then the lock is on particular class instance but we used synchronized (buffer),  what is the difference between these two can anyone explain in depth regarding the differences .here are the classes

```
class Counter implements Runnable
{

  public StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  public int cnt = 0;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    synchronized (buffer)
     {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
  }
}


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter counter = new Counter(); 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(counter);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(counter);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually there isn't too much to say here; strange it took me 10+ minutes to write down my answer.

You see, one of the two threads acquires the lock first; then it counts to 100; then the other takes the lock; and further increases the counter to 200.

And in your case, it really doesn't make any difference if there is

```
synchronized(this)
```

or

```
synchronized(buffer)
```

The point is: in both cases, "this" and "buffer" result in the "same" reference. You see, there is only **one** Counter object in your example; so when those threads call the run method; "counter.this"; and "counter.buffer" have the same effect: the two threads will sync on **one** object.

In order to get to **different** results, you could rework your example to:

```
public static StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
public static int ...
```

And then use **two** counter objects:

```
Counter counter1 = new Counter(); 
Counter counter2 = new Counter(); 

Thread t1 = new Thread(counter1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(counter2);
```

When you do that, you will find that sync(buffer) still gives you 200 in the end; whereas sync(this) can give you all kind of results.

Because now, counter1.this and counter2.this are not the same object; whereas counter1.buffer and counter2.buffer are!

In other words: when different threads are "updating" the same object; then they **have** to synchronize on the **same** lock. Because, if they sync on **different** lock objects; surprise - then there is no locking, no synchronizing; and therefore: random writes in parallel, with the known result of unpredictability!

Answer (score 0):

One common misunderstanding that people have about intrinsic locks is they get the idea that acquiring the lock does something to protect the properties of the object. If that is what you are thinking, that is not the case.

Every object can have its lock acquired, but that doesn't have any effect on the rest of the object. In this example there is one Runnable that is shared between threads, and that Runnable has one StringBuffer. So as long as there is one lock that is shared, it makes no difference whether that lock is on `this` (in the Runnable) or on the StringBuffer, or on a dedicated lock object (meaning an instance member `private final Object LOCK = new Object()`.

The only possible issue with which object is used to lock on (which would possibly be of concern in bigger multi-threaded programs) is the scope of availability of the lock. There is an argument that using `this` to lock on can be bad due to the lock being available to other threads that could also acquire the lock on it. Reducing the scope of the lock to a private instance member (the StringBuffer or the dedicated lock object) makes it easier to reason about who can acquire the lock.

Answer (score 0):

The difference becomes clearer when you have more than one shared resource in your `class`. You can expand your example to two `counters`. Now locking on `this` would mean that `countA` and `countB` cannot be executed by different `threads` at the same time, although these methods are independent. If you have a lock for each resource you only ensure that `countA` and `countB` cannot be executed simultanously. It is still possible that one `thread` executes `countA` and the other `countB` at the same time.

```
class Counter implements Runnable {

    private StringBuffer lockA = new StringBuffer();
    private int cntA = 0;
    private StringBuffer lockB = new StringBuffer();
    private int cntB = 0;

    public void countA() {
        synchronized (lockA) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                cntA++;
            }
            System.out.println("countA:" + cntA);
        }

    }

    public void countB() {
        synchronized (lockB) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                cntB++;
            }
            System.out.println("countB:" + cntB);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        countA();
        countB();
    }
}
```

Comment: still its confusing can you provide any example related with jdbc or collections